# CXF with 2-Way-SSL: How to exclude generated WSDL from client authentication requirement?

Tags: java, ssl, wsdl, cxf, karaf

after a lot of work I finally got a Two-Way-SSL WebService (Client & Server authentication) running on an OSGi (karaf 3.0.3) runtime environment via apache cxf.

It works very well but the generated WSDL underlies the same security mechanism. Meaning that I cannot receive the generated WSDL via browser or soapUI.

Is there a way to exclude the WSDL from the client authentication?

Here is my blueprint.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws" xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core">

    <jaxws:endpoint id="someWS"
        implementor="#someWebService" address="https://localhost:9443/services/someWS" />

    <httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
        <httpj:engine port="9443">
            <httpj:tlsServerParameters>
                <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_3DES_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_128_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_256_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
                    <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
                </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            </httpj:tlsServerParameters>
            <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="5"
                maxThreads="15" />
            <httpj:connector>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
                    <argument>
                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                            <property name="keyStore" value="etc/keystores/specificWS.jks" />
                            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="..." />
                            <property name="keyManagerPassword" value="..." />
                            <property name="trustStore" value="etc/keystores/specificWS.jks" />
                            <property name="trustStorePassword" value="..." />
                            <property name="needClientAuth" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </argument>
                    <property name="port" value="9443" />
                    <property name="acceptors" value="4" />
                </bean>
            </httpj:connector>
        </httpj:engine>
    </httpj:engine-factory>
</blueprint>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can achieve this by configuring security on web.xml file. There you can secure only the required URL of the web service.

Comment: @Don As I'm only providing web-services on a karaf, I don't have a web.xml - or am I missing something here?

Comment: sorry I have no idea about karaf. What I mentioned is the way to do on normal application server.